# how to cause refresh to ASP.net Page when page Postback

Tags: asp.net

When the ASP.net Page is Postback the controls inside the table is disappear,

but when i click on button that has that code which cause transfer to the page:

```
Server.Transfer("~/Admins/EditUsers.aspx");
```

all controls appear easy with no problems.

Then,is there is need to make refresh to the page, or what can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A postback already performs a page refresh automatically.

If controls are disappearing, that suggests that you might not be creating them on the postback. Note that tables do not store their contents in ViewState. Is there any chance you are testing for `IsPostBack` in your page `Load` handler? If so, you must recreate the table on every load, whether a postback or not.

Beyond that, you'd probably need to provide a bit more specific information.

Comment: Thanks man, but how to recreate the table every load ??  the table is found already in the page and i add controls to it dynamically by the code (programmatically).

Comment: Just create the table in your page's Load event. I don't know if you saw my comments about `IsPostBack` but I'm still in the dark as to what your code (Load event or anything else) does. And if you find my reply helpful, please upvote or mark as the answer.